# I get an error that stops during npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, node-modules

I get an error that stops during npm install.

error message is
: extract:run-sequence: verb lock using /Users/user/.npm/_locks/staging-19ba47088a6e1908.lock for /Users/user/Desktop/folder_name/node_modules/.staging

node v10.16.3
npm v 6.9.0

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I updated npm and deleted the node_modules directory, and then run npm install, after which it solved this problem. It appears that killing the npm installation process using CTRL + C is causing the `locking`.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following steps I carried out and which worked for me.

1. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file.
2. run `npm cache clean -f` to remove cached data.
3. Update npm using `npm update -g`.
4. try running `npm install`
5. If issue persist try changing your service provider. It can be an issue with proxy related with the provider. Or try using a Virtual Private Network (VPN) instead.